# .NET Core deployment to droplet via Docker error: Runtime stage name already used

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just started with Digitalocean, Dokku and Docker. After looking around quite a bit, I've found nothing which addresses this specific error.

I encounter this error while pushing a .net core application to a Digitalocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04:

```
remote: Step 8/13 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
remote:  ---> Running in c6a4c4b610e6
remote: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
remote: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
remote:
remote:   Restore completed in 86.15 ms for /app/aspnetapp/aspnetapp.csproj.
remote:   aspnetapp -> /app/aspnetapp/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/aspnetapp.dll
remote:   aspnetapp -> /app/aspnetapp/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/aspnetapp.Views.dll
remote:   aspnetapp -> /app/aspnetapp/out/
remote: Removing intermediate container c6a4c4b610e6
remote:  ---> 40a01a03c830
remote: runtime stage name already used
To 159.89.150.200:aspnetapp
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@159.89.150.200:aspnetapp'
```

I've pruned the docker (docker system prune) and the images listed are as expected.

```
REPOSITORY                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                              <none>              3b46c96be3bf        3 minutes ago       1.75GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk   2.2                 f41abe72b459        2 days ago          1.74GB
gliderlabs/herokuish                latest              fa3443ac31b2        2 months ago        1.21GB
gliderlabs/herokuish                v0.5.0              fa3443ac31b2        2 months ago        1.21GB
root@dokku-ubuntu1804-aspnetapp-round2:~#
```

I destroyed the target app (dokku apps:destroy aspnetapp),
reincarnated it (dokku apps:create aspnetapp),
and pushed my local repo out to the server. This did not resolve the issue.

I created a new droplet (with Dokku and Docker preinstalled) and the issue persists.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /app/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000 #
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/aspnetapp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught it when I reviewed the posted Dockerfile.

The first line should read as follows:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS **build**

Answer (score 1):

You can use shorten version like this

```sh
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
```